VirtualBox with Ubuntu 24.04 Hostsystem ; Failed to change display parameter
I installed on an Ubuntu 24.04 host system Virtualbox in the latest version version 7.1.2 r164945 (Qt6.4.2).
When starting an installed virtual machine (Ubuntu 24.10 ), I receive the following error message:
Failed to change display parameter.
The console is not powered up (setVideoModeHint).
Result Code:
E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005)
Component:
DisplayWrap
Interface:
IDisplay {4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de}

Then the virtual machine starts. However, sometimes the screen freezes when I switch to full screen. The problem also arises with another Linux host.
Does anyone have an idea?
Update: In the meantime, I have noticed that this error message will also appear with a Windows 11 host system.
